# Add Inherited Controls to a Panel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a base form with two buttons (e.g. OK and Cancel). I want to use a `TableLayoutPanel` and have the two buttons in it. Child forms should be able to add more controls to the table as well as modify its layout itself via the designer.

So far I can't get this to work. I have tried the following:

- Adding the `TableLayoutPanel` to the child form. Designer refuses to add the two buttons to the panel.
- Adding the `TableLayoutPanel` in the base form. Can't add controls to the panel from the child form.

Comment: I have never had the designer work well for sub classing forms, you may need to use to code to add the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this hasn't received an answer since almost over a year and WindowsForms is slowly losing against WPF, the answer seems to be "just don't do it".

Comment: Yep, as @Ian Ringrose says, the designed wont play ball and hou'll continually be rmoving autogenned code from the derived class. And yes, WPF and friends have a much better story for all of this. Remember the GDI and all the dresses it wears like WinForms are older than you are man and have design warts to match! And the CodeDOM approach hasnt exactly been garnering support...

Answer (score 6):

In the base form you have to set the property Modifiers = Protected for the TableLayoutPanel and any other control you want to change in the child forms.

Comment: Worked for me in VS2012, .NET 4.0; ancestor with a panel with `Modifiers` set to `Protected` (at design time).  Build/save, then edit descendent and add item to the panel - no problems.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you cant edit your `TableLayoutPanel` in the derived class is because you are attempting to use a feature of WinForms called 'visual inheritance'.  Unfortunately, the `TableLayoutPanel` does not support visual inheritance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171689.aspx (read at the bottom of the page) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2.aspx

This is why it appears blocked in the inherited controls.  I am not sure why they do not support this feature, but I have recently come across the same problem and ended up having to solve the problem another way.